# Is 'file' a keyword in python?

Tags: python, keyword

Is `file` a keyword in python?

I've seen some code using the keyword `file` just fine, while others have suggested not to use it and my editor is color coding it as a keyword.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: -1 searching for a list of keywords of a language is both mandatory and natural when trying to learn that language.

Comment: @Solkar To which language do you refer? Python2 or Python3? The confusion of OP is reasonable, imo.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

No, `file` is not a keyword:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.iskeyword('file')
False
```

The name is not present in Python 3. In Python 2, `file` is a built-in:

```
>>> import __builtin__, sys
>>> hasattr(__builtin__, 'file')
True
>>> sys.version_info[:2]
(2, 7)
```

It can be seen as an alias for `open()`, but it was removed in Python 3, where the new [`io` framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) replaced it. Technically, it is the [type of object returned by the Python 2 `open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).

Comment: So is it ok to use `file` as a variable name if I plan to support Python 3 only?

Comment: @GustavoBezerra absolutely!

Answer (score 25):

`file` is neither a *keyword* nor a *builtin* in **Python 3**.

```
>>> import keyword
>>> 'file' in keyword.kwlist
False
>>> import builtins
>>> 'file' in dir(builtins)
False
```

`file` is also used as variable example from Python 3 [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#i-o-base-classes).

```
with open('spam.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('Spam and eggs!')
```

Answer (score 2):

As others suggested, `type` in **Python 3** it is **not** defined by default:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 14 2022, 12:59:47) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

The color coding in VS Code and possibly other editors probably refers to **Python 2**, where it **is** defined by default, it is the type returned by `open()`:

```
Python 2.7.18 (default, Jul  1 2022, 12:27:04) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> file
<type 'file'>
```