# Code issue - file opening

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to define a function that should open the file with the given name, display its contents on the screen, three characters at a time, and then close the file. This version function should crash if it's called with an invalid filename.  However, I think there is a bug in my code that causes it to crash without even running the function.

This is my code so far:

```
def trigram_printer(filename):
    """str -> none"""
    print("Please enter a filename: ")
    filename = input("> ")
    while True:
        try:
            file = open(filename)
            for line in file:
                print(line)
            file.close()
            break
        except IOError:
            print("There was a problem accessing file '" + filename + "'." + \
                  "Please enter a different filename.")
            filename = input(">")
```

For the error message, I actually get the "There was a problem accessing file '" + filename + "'." + \
                  "Please enter a different filename."... so I think it may be working at least a little.  Help me if you can...

Comment: Indentation, you need your code formatted in the function's scope.

Comment: Well, if you're getting an IOError look up the stack trace and see what the original error was.  Or if it's not showing up raise the exception instead of catching it.

Comment: why are you passing argument filename to function and then getting input to filename variable. You are probably overwriting that.

Comment: `except IOError as e: print(e)` will be more informative, as ThePavolC has commented passing an arg you never use is redundant, if you want to use the filename you pass in remove the  first input

Comment: What exactly should this function do ?You want the user to put in file name, then you want to print out content of file, and then return from function ?

Comment: You say 'three chars at a time' but print a line at a time.  You say 'crash' but catch exception.  Which do you want?  Also, you have a filename input parameter, but ignore it and fetch filename within function.

Comment: sorry it has some mistakes @TerryJanReedy i need three chars at a time but crash if the program cant find the filename

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting filename argument passing to function, and you are asking user for file name so there is no need for that at all.

As [heifzhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28866041/2229132) mentioned, you should not use file, as it is a built in, but in Python 3 that's not an issue. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942358/is-file-a-keyword-in-python)

Regarding your task, I would:

1. ask for file name
2. open file
3. read 3 characters while [read()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) won't return ""
4. print 3 characters, or do whatever you want
5. return

Here is my example:

```
def trigram_printer2():
    """str -> none"""
    print("Please enter a filename: ")
    filename = input("> ")
    try:
        opened_file = open(filename)
        three_chars = opened_file.read(3)
        while three_chars != "":
            three_chars = opened_file.read(3)
            print (three_chars)
        opened_file.close()
    except IOError:
        print("There was a problem accessing file '" + filename + "'." + \
              "Please enter a different filename.")
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to indent all function body.

```
def trigram_printer(filename):
  """str -> none"""
  print("Please enter a filename: ")
  filename = input("> ")
  while True:
    try:
        file = open(filename)
        for line in file:
            print(line)
        file.close()
        break
    except IOError:
        print("There was a problem accessing file '" + filename + "'." + \
              "Please enter a different filename.")
        filename = input(">")
```