# Looping over a text file list with python

Tags: python

EDIT: Have updated post for better clarity, no answers have yet to help!

Alright, so my assignment is to take a text file, that would have 4 entries per line, those being firstName, lastName, hours, payRate. I'm to do some calculations and throw all this information in a formatted table in python. Now, I've got the code to enter the data into the table, but it only works for the first entry in the text file, and I can't quite make it loop. I honestly feel like an idiot, and that this is just a simple fix.

My output is supposed to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yH8Z.png

Could really use some pointers on making this loop through and print the data from each line of the text file. Here's how my current code looks:

```
heading1 = "{0:15s}{1:15s}{2:10s}{3:15s}{4:20s}{5:15s}".format("First Name",         "Last Name", "Hours", "Payrate", "Overtime Hours", "Gross Pay")
heading2=    "=============================================================================================================="

print(heading1)
print(heading2)

if os.path.isfile(fileQuestion) == True:
file = open('emps', 'r')
data = file.readlines()
for tmp in data:

    data2= [word.rstrip("\n") for word in data]
    first = data2[0].split()

    lastName = first[0]
    firstName = first[1]
    first[2]=(int(first[2]))
    first[3]=(int(first[3]))
    initialHours = first[2]
    payRate = first[3]

    if initialHours > 40:
        overHours = initialHours - 40
        regHours = 40
        regPay = payRate * regHours
        otPay = overHours * (payRate * 1.5)
        grossPay = regPay + otPay

    else:
        regHours = first[2]
        grossPay = initialHours * payRate
        overHours = 0



    heading3= "{0:15s}{1:15s}{2:2d}{3:10d}{4:14d}   {5:24.2f}".format(firstName, lastName, regHours, payRate, overHours, grossPay)
    heading4= "{0:15s}{1:21.2f}".format("Total Gross Pay", grossPay)
    heading5= "{0:15s}{1:19.2f}".format("Average Gross Pay", grossPay)
    heading6= "{0:15s}{1:16d}".format("Total Overtime Hours", 33)
    spaceHeading = "               "

    print(heading3)
    print(spaceHeading)
print(heading4)
print(heading5)
print(heading6)
```

Please let me know if I haven't done this correctly or anything, first time here. Thanks.

Comment: file.readlines() reads all the lines and puts in a string. You should use f.readline inside a loop. Look up the proper syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the duplicate, and think some people treat rude ;/ Just not focus on pragmatic problems of programmers but on good rules of Stack in bad way :(

Here is my complete answer for your problem:

1)
First of all, you must remember that **ident** is used against code block's brackets known from another landuages.

I reformatted your code remember that all of lines should have extra spaces at the beginning when you pase it here ;)

2) like it was said:

```
first = word.split()
```

fix "not changing" of lines in loop.

3) Total overtime hours have hardcoded number:

```
heading6= "{0:15s}{1:16d}".format("Total Overtime Hours", overHours)
```

Also, overHours(All?) should be not "zeroed" in 'else' block in loop. You must initialize it before loop.

I change some other places i.e. some hardcoded ints, maybe it not ideal and in your style, but you have code with my fixes below...

Best, if you use GitHub or Bitbucket or another repo accesible by web, because you help to contribute if you want it, and also - yourself, to find all the changes which was done. And then, just ask here to help in extremely unknown problems. In the begging of learning it is always hard to find out, but later - you could achieve more!

Here is code after my changes:

```
from os.path import isfile as isFileExsist
import sys

filePath = input("What is the name of your file?: ")

while isFileExsist(filePath) == False:
    pos = ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes']
    neg = ['n', 'N', 'no', 'No']
    answer = input("File not found! Do you want to start again? (y-yes/n-no)")
    if answer in neg:
        exit("Bye!")
    elif answer in pos:
        filePath = input("What is the name of your file?: ")
        continue
    else:
        print("Not sure what is the answer. Try again!")
        continue

file = open(filePath, 'r')
data = file.readlines()

print("{0:15s}{1:15s}{2:10s}{3:15s}{4:20s}{5:15s}".format("First Name",   "Last Name", "Hours", "Payrate", "Overtime Hours", "Gross Pay"))
print("==============================================================================================================")

overHoursAll = 0
grossPayAll = 0
count = 0

for line in data:
    words = line.split()

    lastName = words[0]
    firstName = words[1]
    initialHours=(int(words[2]))
    payRate =(int(words[3]))

    if initialHours > 40:
        regHours = 40
        overHours = initialHours - 40

        regPay = payRate * regHours
        otPay = overHours * (payRate * 1.5)
        grossPay = regPay + otPay
    else:
        regHours = initialHours
        overHours = 0

        grossPay = initialHours * payRate


    grossPayAll += grossPay
    overHoursAll += overHours

    # heading3
    print("{0:15s}{1:15s}{2:2d}{3:10d}{4:14d}{5:24.2f}".format(firstName, lastName, regHours, payRate, overHours, grossPay))
    # space heading
    print("               ")

# overall stats
print("{0:15s}{1:21.2f}".format("Total Gross Pay", grossPayAll))
print("{0:15s}{1:19.2f}".format("Average Gross Pay", grossPayAll / len(data)))
print("{0:15s}{1:16d}".format("Total Overtime Hours", overHoursAll))
```

Best regards, I am sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I *think*, you probably want `data2 = [word.rstrip("\n") for word in tmp]`, but without seeing sample input and desired output it's hard to tell.

Also,

```
first[2]=(int(first[2]))
first[3]=(int(first[3]))
initialHours = first[2]
payRate = first[3]
```

Could be:

```
initialHours = int(first[2])
payRate = int(first[3])
```

But you'd also need to change other references to `first[2]`

Finally, I'd change

```
if os.path.isfile(fileQuestion) == True:
file = open('emps', 'r')
data = file.readlines()
for tmp in data:
```

to:

```
if os.path.isfile(fileQuestion) == True:
with open('emps', 'r') as myfile:
    for tmp in myfile:
```

This ensures that the file gets closed properly (your code doesn't close it), and iterates directly through the file, rather than using `readlines()` which needlessly reads the entire file to memory before doing enything else. Note that `file` is a python [builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24942363/3714940), so a bad choice of variable name.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my desired output, if that clears it up. I'm still having trouble with this after implementing your code. :\ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using these lines:

```
data = file.readlines()
for tmp in data:
```

which already splits your data into lines, and iterates through them. That means that this line [`data2= [word.rstrip("\n") for word in data]`] is setting `data2` to be the first line EVERY TIME, which renders the original for loop useless.

Try instead:

```
tmp = tmp.split()
```

which will split each line as you iterate, you can now call `tmp` as a list, like you called `first` except it will reflect the values for each line.

You could also change your original for loop to:

```
for tmp in file:
```

since file objects in python are generators that yield each line (this saves you some memory space)

Answer (score 0):

try these changes:

```
totothrs = 0
totgross = 0.0
employees = 0
for tmp in data:
    employees += 1
    fname, lname, rate, hrs = tm.split()
    hrs = int(hrs)
    rate = float(rate)
    othrs = 0
    if hrs > 40:
        othrs = hrs - 40
        hrs = hrs - othrs

    totothrs += othrs
    gross = rate * hrs + (1.5*rate)*othrs
    totgross += gross
    heading3= "{0:15s}{1:15s}{2:2d}{3:10d}{4:14d}   {5:24.2f}".format(firstName, lastName, hrs, rate, othrs, gross)
    print heading3

spaceHeading = "       "
heading4= "{0:15s}{1:21.2f}".format("Total Gross Pay", totgross)
heading5= "{0:15s}{1:19.2f}".format("Average Gross Pay", (totgross/employees)
heading6= "{0:15s}{1:16d}".format("Total Overtime Hours", totothrs)

print heading4
print heading5
print heading6
```

Note: you dontneed to define the "headingN"'s you can just print them

Answer (score 0):

```
import os.path
import sys
#fileQuestion = input("What is the name of your file?: ")
fileQuestion = "Testfile.txt"
heading1 = "{0:15s}{1:15s}{2:10s}{3:15s}{4:20s}{5:15s}".format("First Name",   "Last Name", "Hours", "Payrate", "Overtime Hours", "Gross Pay")
heading2=    "=============================================================================================================="

print(heading1)
print(heading2)

if os.path.isfile(fileQuestion) == True:
    file_handle = open(fileQuestion, 'r')
#file = open('emps', 'r')
#data = file.readlines()    I would't go for readline here

#file_handle2 = open('outupt.txt')
total_gross_pay = 0
number_of_employees = 0
average_gross_pay = 0
total_overtime = 0
standard_working_hours = 40

for i in file_handle:
    data = i.rstrip().lstrip().split()

    #print (data)
    first_name, last_name, hours, payrate = data

    hours = int(hours)
    payrate = int(payrate)
    basic_pay = hours * payrate

    if(hours > standard_working_hours):
        overtime = hours - standard_working_hours
        overtime_premium = overtime * payrate
        gross_pay = overtime_premium + basic_pay

    else:
        overtime = 0
        gross_pay = basic_pay

    total_overtime += overtime
    total_gross_pay += gross_pay
    number_of_employees += 1

    print("{0:15s}{1:15s}{2:10s}{3:15s}{4:20s}{5:15s}".format(first_name, last_name, str(hours), str(payrate), str(overtime), str(gross_pay)))

print('\n')
print("Total Gross Pay:   ",total_gross_pay)
print("Average Gross Pay: ",total_gross_pay/number_of_employees)
print("Total overtime:    ",total_overtime)
```

Comment: The above code works well for the input format of the textfile you described I hope you find it useful.