# How can I solve "Name file is not defined"

Tags: python

When I run my Python command I keep seeing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  file "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

Can someone send my a copy from the following code but then good with a explain.

```
file = raw_input("Enter the file name: ")
file = open(file, "r")
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: The code you posted here won't give you that error.

Comment: this is working for me. I would strongly recommend not using the variable name `file` though because that is a built in type name.

Comment: what are you are importing ...??

Comment: You seem to use a python version 2 (derived from raw_input() function), there file is a builtin (`__builtin__` has it as attribute and as @MartijnPieters already pointed out in his answer to [Is 'file' a keyword in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942358/is-file-a-keyword-in-python): "It can be seen as an alias for open(), but it has been removed from Python 3, as the new io framework replaced it. Technically, it is the type of object returned by the open() function." Otherwise please state a code, that **really** produces the name error.

Comment: I dont know but it really gives my that error. @MartijnPieters You are dutch. Can you help me in Dutch?

Comment: @Iseehie: sorry, even in Dutch I can't help here.

Comment: I have tried it with thefile. It doesnt work.

Comment: Are you able to show the whole source code so we can have a better idea of what might be happening?