# NLTK saving trained Brill's model

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger, nltk-trainer, brill-tagger

I am training a Brill's POS tagger using the `py-crfsuite` as provided in NLTK. However when I try to save a trained model, I get the following error:

```
crf_tagger = CRFTagger()    
crf_tagger.train(train_sents, 'model_trained.crf.tagger')
templates = nltk.tag.brill.nltkdemo18()
trainer = nltk.tag.brill_trainer.BrillTaggerTrainer(crf_tagger, templates)
bt = trainer.train(train_sents, max_rules=10)

file_writing = file('trained_brill_tagger.yaml', 'w')
yaml.dump(bt, file_writing)

#even pickle fails
file_w = open('trained_brills.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(bt, file_w)
file_w.close()
```

> File "stringsource", line 2, in pycrfsuite._pycrfsuite.Tagger.**reduce_cython**
> TypeError: self.c_tagger cannot be converted to a Python object for pickling

I have tried using `pickle`, `dill` and also `yaml` however the error seems to persist. Is there any solution to this. Is this because of using CRF tagger as baseline? Thank you.

Comment: What is `file`? Could you show the code before the snippet you've posted? Also, where did you get this code snippet from?

Comment: @alvas file is a default function in python to open a file. I also tried open(). I followed documentation on nltk.tag to train the model and tried yaml when pickle did not work for me since the issues section for nltk at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/555 mentioned yaml. I keep getting the same error though.

Comment: I don't think file is a default function in Python ;P The native Python function should be `open()`

Comment: @alvas file? in ipython console shows it as a command and it works perfectly fine. I have shown more source as you asked.

Comment: Could you show your imports? I think you've imported some rogue libraries using a Python builtin `file`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942358/is-file-a-keyword-in-python

Comment: Okay, I think you're on Python2. Which NLTK version are you using? `import nltk; print(nltk.__version__)`

Comment: @alvas 3.2.5 version. I removed file and tried too. I will replace CRF with StanfordPOSTagger and try. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I realized the issue is in the `CRFTagger` module. If I use a different initial tagger with Brill's, the error isn't produced and model gets saved.

```
trainer = nltk.tag.brill_trainer.BrillTaggerTrainer(baseline_tagger, templates)
```

I was unable to save the trained model when baseline_tagger was a `CRFTagger()` object. Using something like an `NgramTagger` solves the issue for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can train a `nltk.tag.brill_trainer.BrillTaggerTrainer` in NLTK v3.2.5

```
from nltk.corpus import treebank

from nltk.tag import BrillTaggerTrainer, RegexpTagger, UnigramTagger
from nltk.tbl.demo import REGEXP_TAGGER, _demo_prepare_data, _demo_prepare_data
from nltk.tag.brill import describe_template_sets, brill24

baseline_backoff_tagger = REGEXP_TAGGER
templates = brill24()
tagged_data = treebank.tagged_sents()
train=0.8
trace=3
num_sents=1000
randomize=False
separate_baseline_data=False

(training_data, baseline_data, gold_data, testing_data) = \
   _demo_prepare_data(tagged_data, train, num_sents, randomize, separate_baseline_data)

baseline_tagger = UnigramTagger(baseline_data, backoff=baseline_backoff_tagger)

# creating a Brill tagger
trainer = BrillTaggerTrainer(baseline_tagger, templates, trace, ruleformat="str")
```

Then to save the trainer, simply `pickle`:

```
import pickle
with open('brill-demo.pkl', 'wb') as fout:
    pickle.dump(trainer, fout)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I realized the issue is in the CRFTagger module in NLTK. If i replace that with some other model while training my Brill's tagger, the error goes away.

Comment: BTW, where did the CRFTagger come from?

Comment: I trained one CRFTagger as well. I wanted to check how changing templates with Brill's will affect performance of the CRFTagger which is available in nltk.tag.