# print list line by line in python

Tags: python, list

I am new in python and I am trying to print a list line by line.

```
fp = open(filepath) # Open file on read mode
lines = fp.read().split("\n")   #Create a list with each line

print(lines) #Print the list

for line in lines:
    print(line) #Print each line

fp.close()
```

But it's printing in one line.

The contents of the text file are

```
peat1,1,11345674565,04-11-2018
peat2,0,11345674565,05-11-2018
peat3,1,11345674565,06-11-2018
peat4,0,11345674565,07-11-2018
```

And it is printing as

```
peat1,1,11345674565,04-11-2018 peat2,0,11345674565,05-11-2018 peat3,1,11345674565,06-11-2018 peat4,0,11345674565,07-11-2018
```

The environment is -- Python 3.4 and running under Apache through cgi-bin

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It should work. Perhaps your file only has 1 line? How many elements does your `lines` list contain? Can you include a portion of the file as well?

Comment: Use `print(len(lines))` to check the how many lines file has.

Comment: @RedCricket Before posting here I have explored 3-4 similar posts but not the one which you mentioned. The reason is my txt file has got only 4 lines so it's not a large file.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra your approach **should work** so there is something you aren't showing us. You really need to provide a [mcve], and at the very least, the output you are seeing.

Comment: @slider Updated the post.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Please see the updated post if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra It's working fine for me: https://trinket.io/python/23a9bb3d00

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Are you in Windows?

Comment: Sorted. it's `print("<br>")` if I am running through cgi-bin.

Answer (score 0):

With large files, you are better off reading files line by line, like so:

```
with open('filename') as file: 
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

I suggest this approach with `with`, which handles closing the file pointer itself.

Comment: There approach *should* work, though, even if it is less than ideal. And in any event, if this were the answer, then it would be a clear duplicate and should be closed

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I added a reason to use this approach than OPs. :)

Comment: But that doesn't answer the purported question, because the OP claims the approach *doesn't* work, and indeed if it doesn't, then this approach wouldn't work either. The OP needs to add more details and a MCVE

Comment: I would suggest to use another var name than file, because `file` is a language key name. What if fp for file pointer?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi not in Python 3.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942358/is-file-a-keyword-in-python